# Undefined index: Warning in SuiteCRM 7.5.5

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I downloaded SuiteCRM 7.5.5.from Suitecrm website. This one is my first installation of SuiteCRM. After I installed, in accounts, Contact, Leads I got this warnings.

> Notice: Undefined index: CampaignLog in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SuiteCRM\include\SearchForm\SearchForm2.php on line
>   129
>
> Notice: Undefined index: LBL_AOP_INTERNAL in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SuiteCRM\modules\AOP_Case_Updates\Case_Updates.php on
>   line 305
>
> Notice: Undefined index: AOS_Products_Quotes in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\SuiteCRM\include\SearchForm\SearchForm2.php on line
>   129

I reinstalled again, loaded and unloaded sample database, but for everything I got this same warning.
This warning shows below the overview form (middle of the page) in Accounts. Below that I have options to add Activities, history etc., but all options don't have icons.Im using Mozilla Firefox

When I tried this Chrome, I got warnings but icons are displayed.

Comment: I'm having the same problem...  Any solution?

Comment: No..Still the same.

Answer (score 0):

PHP provides various levels of feedback to developers in the form of notices, warnings and on occasion errors. Some of these can be ignored and are only used to inform programmers of best practices (and violations there of) and others, such as errors, as you suspect, need to be addressed.

With regards to SugarCRM we recommend turning display errors to off. This will prevent all of these notifications from being written to the screen and will shield users from being distracted by warnings and notices. You can change this setting for on-site (self-hosted) instances by locating your `php.ini` file and making sure the `display_errors = Off`. You will need to restart the web server for these changes to take effect.

To summarize: Warnings and Notices can be ignored and only fatal errors which interfere with the execution of the application need to be reported to support.

Help Link : http://support.sugarcrm.com/Knowledge_Base/Troubleshooting/About_PHP_Notices_Warnings_and_Errors/